# How to block a Countries IP range with a Cisco ASA?

Tags: cisco-asa, access-control-list, ip-blocking

To be more specific I have a request from a client to block China's IP range. I know how to do this. I would use the IPs from https://www.countryipblocks.net/e_country_data/CN_netmask.txt and make a ACL. Well if you take a look at that there are 3,412 networks I would have to block.

What I'm really asking is there a way around making a super large ACL? If it was contiguous IP space I could just supernet but that is not the case.

Comment: You could do a block on a router by AS Number (smaller list of stuff to block), but not sure about doing it on a firewall...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a gigantic network object group is more to your liking than a gigantic ACL, then I guess that'd be the other option.  It's the same level of ugly in the command line and in execution, but it'd make it prettier in ASDM, I suppose.

Be very careful of blanket blocks of countries; I've seen it cause some interesting issues.  ("Why can't I get to Windows Update?" "Oh, you're hitting an Indonesian server, and someone blocked all of Asia")

Comment: yeah if it would happen it would have been added as big ol' network object.

Comment: Guess there isn't another way to do this. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2):

I've created a script where all you have to do is choose an authority and it'll give you the configuration to drop into the ASA. It's incredibly accurate.

[regional-asa](https://github.com/in-transit/regional-asa)

You can block or allow a specific region if you want. I'll be updating it soon to do specific countries but now it does authorities like ARIN, RIPE, APNIC, etc.